# Non-throwing version of Seq.exactlyOne to test for a singleton sequence

Tags: f#, singleton, sequence, seq

**Update**: I created a UserVoice request for this: [Expand on the Cardinality functions for Seq](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/16308904-expand-on-cardinality-functions-seq-exactlyone-wi).

I need the functionality of `Seq.exactlyOne`, but with Some/None semantics. In other words, I need either `Seq.head`, or, if the sequence is empty or contains more than one item, I need nothing. Using `Seq.exactlyOne` will throw in such cases.

I don't think there's a built-in way of getting this (though it sounds so trivial that one would expect there is a counterpart for `Seq.singleton`). I came up with this, but it feels convoluted:

```
let trySingleton sq = 
    match Seq.isEmpty sq with 
    | true -> None 
    | false -> 
        match sq |> Seq.indexed |> Seq.tryFind (fst >> ((=) 1)) with
        | Some _ -> None
        | None -> Seq.exactlyOne sq |> Some
```

Gives:

```
> trySingleton [|1;2;3|];;
val it : int option = None
> trySingleton Seq.empty<int>;;
val it : int option = None
> trySingleton [|1|];;
val it : int option = Some 1
```

Is there a simpler, or even a built-in way? I could try/catch on `Seq.exactlyOne`, but that is building business logic around exceptions, I'd rather not (and it is expensive).

*UPDATE:*
I wasn't aware of the `Seq.tryItem` function, which would make this simpler:

```
let trySingleton sq =
    match sq |> Seq.tryItem 1 with
    | Some _ -> None
    | None -> Seq.tryHead sq
```

(better, but it still feels rather awkward)

Comment: BTW, you can suggest `tryExactlyOne` as an addition to the language: https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language I'd add the suggestion myself, but I'm out of votes on that forum.

Comment: @MarkSeemann: done, as [can be seen here](https://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/16308904-expand-on-cardinality-functions-seq-exactlyone-wi), tx for the suggestion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not approach the problem by handling the enumerator imperatively?

```
let trySingleton' (xs : seq<_>) =
    use en = xs.GetEnumerator()
    if en.MoveNext() then
        let res = en.Current
        if en.MoveNext() then None
        else Some res
    else None

trySingleton' Seq.empty<int>    // None
trySingleton' [1]               // Some 1
trySingleton' [1;2]             // None
```

Comment: It's not "simpler", but it feels "cleaner". Either answer shows that there isn't a trivial (meaning: core library) approach that I missed. Rather arbitrary between the two solutions, I'll accept this one for its creativity and cleanliness, thanks :).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not aware of a built-in function for this, but here's an alternative way to implement it:

```
let tryExactlyOne xs =
    match xs |> Seq.truncate 2 |> Seq.toList with
    | [x] -> Some x
    | _   -> None
```

FSI demo:

```
> [42] |> List.toSeq |> tryExactlyOne;;
val it : int option = Some 42

> [42; 1337] |> List.toSeq |> tryExactlyOne;;
val it : int option = None

> Seq.empty<int> |> tryExactlyOne;;
val it : int option = None
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that `truncate` didn't throw, but the docs say it clearly ("at most X items). Nice solution! Not sure whether the `Seq.toList` will have a detrimental impact on performance, but since this will only ever be a 0, 1 or 2 items list, I'd expect it to be of little influence.

Comment: @Abel You'll need to attempt to iterate twice in order to determine if the item is a singleton, so I don't think you can do it more efficiently than this (`Seq.truncate` is lazy). Both kaefer's and your own solution also iterate twice.

Comment: Yep, that's true. Though your and my solution iterate twice on call (at least, I think), kaefer's does not iterate twice on call, but will reset the iteration pointer, so the second iteration comes only in the more-than-one scenario. As such, I think his solution is 'cleaner".

Comment: @Abel The same is true for `Seq.truncate`. It uses `IEnumerator.MoveNext` under the covers: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/seq.fs#L1250-L1257